# Kubernetes nginx ingress shows "403" after configuring path field

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

Below is my manifests:

- service.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: jenkins
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
   - port: 8080
     protocol: TCP
     targetPort: 8080
     nodePort: 80
  selector:
    app: jenkins
  #externalTrafficPolicy: "Cluster"
```

- ingress.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-entry
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    #nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    #ingress.bluemix.net/rewrite-path: "serviceName=jenkins rewrite=/"

spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - ingress.hygon.cn
    secretName: nginx-cert
  rules:
  - host: ingress.hygon.cn
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /jenkins
        backend:
          serviceName: jenkins
          servicePort: 8080
```

I use an nginx ingress to control access backend service Jenkins.
If I set http.paths.path equal "/" everything works well, but if I set path field for the URL the browser will show a 403 error.

Comment: Do you have any specific reason for using `nodePort` here ? Simple `ClusterIP` service would suffice. Simply remove `type: NodePort` and `nodePort: 80` fields. Most probably you won't be able to expose it on port `80` of your node IP anyway, unless you start your **kube-apiserver** with `--service-node-port-range portRange` flag and specify different port range e.g. something like `1-1024`.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify what URLs you are hitting from the outside. But I'm guessing with `http.paths.path: /` you were hitting:

```sh
http://hosname/jenkins
```

Then you modified it to `http.paths.path: /jenkins`, and hitting the same URL you are getting a `403`. If that's the case you need to remove `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /` because that's actually rewriting `/jenkins` to `/` and your Jenkins server doesn't know how to serve it.

Alternatively, you can just change the configs on your Jenkins server to serve under `/` and keep the current setup with `http.paths.path: /jenkins` and `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /`.

✌️

Comment: My purpose is I can access jenkins server in backend by typing "https://hostname/jenkins", just like nginx reverse proxy.